# RuntimeError: Error while calling cudaGetDevice(&the_device_id) in file gpu_data.cpp:201. code: 30, reason: unknown error

Tags: python, c++, nvidia, dlib

I am getting following error while initializing the face detector model `dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1(path)`.

```
RuntimeError: Error while calling cudaGetDevice(&the_device_id) in file gpu_data.cpp:201. code: 30, reason: unknown error
```

This get away with this error by simply restarting the machine. Since, this can't be done if it occurs frequently in future, so I would like to understand the cause of this error. With little research I found this is somewhat related to driver version, but what is exactly wrong with the initialization is still a question for me.

Below mentioned information may be useful:

```
>>> nvidia-smi -a 

==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Tue Feb 18 15:15:45 2020
Driver Version                      : 410.129
CUDA Version                        : 10.0

Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Product Name                    : GeForce GTX 1070 with Max-Q Design
    Product Brand                   : GeForce
    Display Mode                    : Enabled
    Display Active                  : Enabled
    Persistence Mode                : Enabled
    Accounting Mode                 : Disabled
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size     : 4000
```

```
>>> nvidia-smi

Tue Feb 18 15:21:48 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.129      Driver Version: 410.129      CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 107...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P0    31W /  N/A |    483MiB /  8117MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      3465      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            18MiB |
|    0      3597      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          48MiB |
|    0      6012      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           213MiB |
|    0      6148      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         199MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am looking for some explanation for this error. Solution for it is more than welcome.

Comment: Where you able to find solution to this problem?